# WPF Target Invocation Exception in WindowsBase.dll

Tags: wpf, targetinvocationexception

I am working on issue from WPF, which occurs occasionally on client side. Unfortunately, the client is reluctant to provide backup or connection string of his database and I am not allowed to install any external application for diagnosis. So, only thing in my hand is to try to reproduce it. However, I am trying to get solution in parallel from experts on this forum.

At the first look, it seems issue might be due to Scroll Viewer control, as I can see stack trace:

```
at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.ValidateInputOffset    (Double offset, String parameterName) at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.
```

However, at high end, I am getting an unhandled exception as:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException occurred in WindowsBase.dll
```

in my application.

Looking into more details of the error I found exception message as:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Inner Exception shows message:

```
offset parameter value cannot be Nan.Parameter name: offset. Inner Exception Source is Presentation Framework.
```

And here is the detailed stack trace from client side:

```
    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]     arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)  
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,     Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)  
    at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)  
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate    callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)  
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)  
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()  
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)  
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)  
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)  
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)  
    at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)  
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
    at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)  
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)  
    at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)  
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)  
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)  
    at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)  
    at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)  
    at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)  
    at AvocetVM.App.Main()
```

Does anybody came across this kind of issue Or anybody knows the solution to it?

Comment: This stack trace is incredibly generic, it's basically the top most exception from any WPF application.  It's unlikely without some actual code or a more specific exception that anyone will be able to help you with this.

Comment: I cleaned up the error formatting so that it looks better.